# Mongo equivalent of SQL's SELECT DISTINCT?

Tags: php, mongodb, distinct

As per the title, what would be the PHP Mongo equivalent of something like this in SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(field) FROM table WHERE someCondition = 1
```

I've read looked at [this table](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/SQL+to+Mongo+Mapping+Chart) but I don't see how to map `db.users.distinct('last_name')` into PHP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just issue a [command](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.command.php) and set the `distinct` key.

Take a look at the following example from the docs:

**Finding all of the distinct values for a key.**

```
<?php

$people = $db->people;

$people->insert(array("name" => "Joe", "age" => 4));
$people->insert(array("name" => "Sally", "age" => 22));
$people->insert(array("name" => "Dave", "age" => 22));
$people->insert(array("name" => "Molly", "age" => 87));

$ages = $db->command(array("distinct" => "people", "key" => "age"));

foreach ($ages['values'] as $age) {
    echo "$age\n";
}

?>
```

**The above example will output something similar to:**

```
4
22
87
```

Comment: This answer doesn't address the "WHERE" clause

Answer (score 4):

If you need to add a where clause, use the following syntax:

```
$ages = $db->command(array(
    "distinct" => "people", 
    "key" => "age",
    "query" => array("someField" => "someValue")));
```