# Retrieve fields of Mongo collection in PHP

Tags: php, php-mongodb

I tried using the `fields()` method on the cursor:

```
<?php
$mongo  = new Mongo("mongodb://localhost");
print_r($mongo);

$db = $mongo->test;

// access collection
$collection = $db->test;

// execute query
// retrieve all documents
print_r($test);

$cursor = $collection->find();
print_r($cursor);

$fields = $cursor->fields(array("summary" => true));
print_r($fields);
```

The output is:

```
Mongo Object ( [connected] => 1 [status] => [server:protected] => [persistent:protected] => )
MongoCursor Object ( )
MongoCursor Object ( )
```

Looks like the driver and the connection work but I can't retrieve the distinct summarization of the fields.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that we have access to mongodb database with the name *db*, are going to retrieve data from *MyCollection* and use *MongoDB\Driver\Manager*:

```
  $manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager( $DB_CONNECTION_STRING );
```

Then we retrieve data in this case by *name* with a limit *2* documents and want to get **only fields** *name*, *age* and *address* among many others. **Projection** option can be used to specify which fields should be returned using **0** to exclude and **1** to include:

```
  $filter = ['name' => 'John'];
  $options = [ 'projection' => ['_id' => 0, 'name' => 1, 'age' => 1, 'address' => 1], 'limit' => 2 ];
  $query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter, $options);
  $manager->executeQuery('db.MyCollection', $query);
```

If we need to get all columns, then we simply omit **projection** option at all as the following:

```
  $filter = ['name' => 'daniel'];
  $options = [];
  $query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter, $options);
  $manager->executeQuery('db.MyCollection', $query);
```

Comment: I don't know the fields beforehand. In 2013 I needed to get fields before knowing them.

Comment: Hopefully, the added part of the answer will fit your situation

Comment: It doesnt. How does this summarize the fields(~columns) available in a collection?

Answer (score -1):

```
 const HOST = 'localhost';
 const PORT = 27017;
 const DBNAME = 'test';
 const COLLECTION = 'test';
 $connectionString = sprintf('mongodb://%s:%d', HOST, PORT);

 try {

        $connection = new Mongo($connectionString);
        $database = $connection->selectDB(DBNAME);

 } catch (MongoConnectionException $e) {

        throw $e;

}
$collection = $database->selectCollection(COLLECTION);

try{
        $query = array();
        $specifyKey = array("summary" => true);
        $cursor = $collection->find($query , $specifyKey);

}catch(MongoException $e) {

        die('Failed to find One data '.$e->getMessage());

}catch (MongoCursorException $e) {

    echo "error message: ".$e->getMessage()."\n";
    echo "error code: ".$e->getCode()."\n";
}

while ($cursor->hasNext()){

    $nextCursor = $cursor->getNext(); 
    //process next cursor
}
```

Answer (score -2):

After the $cursor variable try an foreach instead. It goes through the cursor results.

```
foreach($cursor as $document) {  
 var_dump($document);  
}
```

Comment: this works to fetch all rows (works for `find()`), I guess there is no way to get all distinct fields available in a collection?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5236160/mongo-equivalent-of-sqls-select-distinct

Comment: This fetches distinct values, but I need distinct keys :-(
Like in my sample above, I need "name, randomNumber" as a result